# How to set the bundle identifier of a cocoapod

Tags: cocoapods, bundle-identifier, podspec

For a pod I have created, cocoapod set org.cocoapods as prefix for the bundle identifier of my pod:

[image]

I would like to be able to set my own prefix but I did not find any option to do that in a podspec.

Anyone knows if this option exists ?

Regards.
Sébastien.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your own plist file for your development pod, like this:

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
  'INFOPLIST_FILE' => '${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/Resources/YourPod-Info.plist'
}
```

Then you just need to just to change `Bundle identifier` inside of that plist.

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide both

> s.info_plist = {
> 'CFBundleIdentifier' => 'com.myorg.mylib'
> }
>
> s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
> 'PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER': 'com.myorg.mylib'
> }

Comment: For info.plist you can alternatively supply this: s.info_plist = { 'CFBundleIdentifier' => '$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)' }

Answer (score 0):

To date, this option does not exists : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4632#issuecomment-162531257

Regards.
Sébastien.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use the post_install handler. Here is a sample script :

```
post_install do |installer|

  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.name == 'BREnterprise'
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]'] = 'iPhone Distribution: The Carter Group LLC'
        config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE'] = '${BR_ENTERPRISE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE}'
      end
    end
  end

  # change bundle id of each pod to 'com.bottlerocketapps.*'
  bundle_id = 'com.bottlerocketapps'

  directory = installer.config.project_pods_root + 'Target Support Files/'
  Dir.foreach(directory) do |path|

    full_path = directory + path
    if File.directory?(full_path)

      info_plist_path = full_path + 'Info.plist'
      if File.exist?(info_plist_path)

        text = File.read(info_plist_path)
        new_contents = text.gsub('org.cocoapods', bundle_id)
        File.open(info_plist_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do it from [this answer](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3032#issuecomment-509493754)

Info.plist DSL will be included in the 1.8.0 release.

To set the bundle identifier:

```
# in .podspec
s.info_plist = {
  'CFBundleIdentifier' => 'com.myorg.mylib'
}
```

Current Cocoapods version is 1.8.0 beta2. I just tried this version and it works. But if you use "pod trunk push", some error messages showed up "The Pod Specification did not pass validation." Maybe we need to wait until the 1.8.0 version release.